# long polling php

Tags: php, ajax

Добрый вечер. Гуглил очень много по этому вопросу, но так и не нашел ответа.
У меня есть кнопка она отправляет пустой ajax запрос в файл test.php

```
 $('.send-test').click(function(){
 $.post( "test.php", {})
  .done(function( data ) {
  });
 });
```

И я никак не могу сделать сервер на php чтобы запрос держался.
В БД у меня есть строчка на ее изменение нужно чтобы выводило echo 'Ok'; 
Делал примерное так через через цикл whil

```
 $one = 0
 $two= (Берем значение из БД )
 while($one == $two){
 echo 'Запрос висит';
 }
echo 'Ok';
```

Но наверное я вообще делаю не так, так как ничего не работает.

Comment: Наверняка, `$one-new` - не то, что вы задумывали

Comment: В php не существует переменных с дефисом(`-`).

Comment: @mix, не всё так однозначно: `${'}---{'}`